# Node express server always shuts down

Tags: node.js, angular, express, nohup

I have a angular app running in a universal express server.
I start the server with

```
nohup node server.js &
exit
```

The server runs fine, but after a while 5 to 30 Minutes it stops with nothing in the nohup logs.

Same happens with forever or pm2, after a while the server is gone without any hint for the error.

Any ideas how to debug, this is on a hosting environment.

Thanks

Comment: A start would be to install node.js and the project on your pc and try to reproduce the issue. Try putting in something that will cause and error and check if it's the same result.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant reproduce the problem locally. The server runs fine